# ASP.Net ADFS Token Encryption certificate private key

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, adfs

According to this link https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2015/03/01/adfs-deep-dive-onboarding-applications/

I have set up a token encryption certificate on the relying party, and exported the public key to the ADFS provider

What changes do I need to make in my asp.net web.config to be able to descrypt these claims. I currently use `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` class to get the claims back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it working now, for any one else. The following needs to be changed in web.config. Replace XXXX with your certificate thumbprint

```
<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <serviceCertificate>
        <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="XXXX" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
      </serviceCertificate>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      <wsFederation ... />
    </federationConfiguration>

  </system.identityModel.services>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of changes made to web.config when enabling ADFS as an identity provider. I often find it easier to simply create a new MVC project, and use the change authentication wizard to select ADFS. Once you have entered the details, it will automatically update the web.config with the required settings, which you can then copy to another project.

Below I have attempted to list all the entries that are required, however I may have missed some.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://YOURADFS/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:Realm" value="https://YOURURL/" />
    <add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="https://YOURURL/" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="YOURMACHINEKEY" decryptionKey="YOURDECRYPTIONKEY" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://YOURURL/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="http://YOURADFS/adfs/services/trust">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="YOURCERTIFICATETHUMB" />
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="http://YOURADFS/adfs/services/trust" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" name="YOURCOOKIENAME" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://YOURADFS/adfs/ls/" realm="https://YOURURL/" requireHttps="true" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
```

You will of course have to replace these values with the corresponding values for your own environment.

Comment: which of these is the private key for token encrytion certificate?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the certificate must be installed on the server in the computer personal store, with the private key available. You then specify which certificate to use by putting its thumbprint in the <add thumbprint=""> section

Comment: Ah that is the certificate on the ADFS server if I am nor wrong? I am talking about the certifcate created by the Relying party and exported to adfs provider

Comment: Yes that was the one I was thinking of. I had forgotten about the relay party signing as its not something we use on any of our setups. Are you sure you need it, as it is an optional feature

Comment: Yes the adfs provider is insisting on it, but I cannot find any help on how to modify we.config to decrypt the claims

Comment: Hmm something sounds odd to me, which may just be a sign of how long its been since I last did this, but I seem to recall that the relay party signing is only used for inbound to ADFS, the claims that are sent back should use the ordinary ADFS cert for encryption, so the thumb method mentioned above should still work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106734/discussion-between-tichra-and-codedbeard).